# location listner do not calling onlocation change

Tags: android, location, listener

I am using location listener in my app.
I have the code like:

```
    public void startlistning()
    {   
            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                location.getLatitude(); 
                location.getLongitude();
            }
        };
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

---

But don't know why the method onLocationChanged did not call when I restart device 1st time (without cellular data (no simcard) available). however, I am using best provider in my app.
Please look into matter. Thanks

Comment: You might want to give some details around how you are invoking this method.

Comment: I simply calling the method startlistning() on activity start. For calling getLastKnownLocation() , I have created a separate class MyLocationListner and then calling the getLastKnownLocation() as below in comment. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location listener method call when you change the location of device . Its not start when you restart device . If you want to invoke `onLocationChanged` method you have to change the location of device .

---

Please try this to get last known location.

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria locationCritera = new Criteria();
    locationCritera.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    locationCritera.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    locationCritera.setBearingRequired(false);
    locationCritera.setCostAllowed(true);
    locationCritera.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

    String providerName = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCritera, true);
    Location location  = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providerName);

    Log.i("--- Latitude",""+location.getLatitude());
    Log.i("--- Latitude",""+location.getLongitude());
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to open get last known location without starting google map? As I am unable to get location in my application when I restart device.

Comment: Hi, I add code for get last known location then stored into shared preference when every time location change, so when ever you restart device you can get it from shared preference.

Comment: Actually I am doing the same things in my app, however, I am unable to get data from wi-fi network. It's working very fine for cellular data. The same code I am placing for your reference. Please see if something need to change or add. My code for last known location is as:

Comment: public Location getLastKnownLocation()
  {
 Location location=new Location(bestProvider);
 try
 {
 // Get the location manager...
 mLocMgr = (LocationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 //Get best location provider by method..  
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();  
 bestProvider = mLocMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
 location = mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  Log.i("location exception", e.getMessage());
 }
 return location;
  
  }